# Can JNDI be used to override local log4j log directory? If yes how

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, tomcat7

Am using tomcat server. Want to override the log file location to a directory in repository by looking up the JNDI.

Comment: LMGTFY:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html

Comment: I found that link but am very new in programming and couldnt undertand. 
eg
where do i add the jndi lookup code  <File name="Application" fileName="application.log">.